# XNA ball movement

Tags: c#, xna

XNA related:

I need help with this minor problem, so the thing is I would like to first get a random number from 1 to 4, and then based on the value of that number the ball will move ( 1(forward,up), 2(backward,up), 3(forward,down), 4(backward,down) ).

In my code I'm checking if the game is played at the moment, so that the ball can get it's direction only at the beggining of the round. (If player wins or dies, the isRoundPlayin is set to false, and when the ball gets random direction (1, 2, 3 or 4) then it's set to true.

```
bool isRoundPlayin = false; // this is at the top of my Game1.cs 

//...
//...
//...
// This is an Update method in Game1.cs:

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

        if (isRoundPlayin == false)
        {
            BallMove();
            isRoundPlayin = true;
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
//...
//...
//...

// This is BallMove method at the end of Game1.cs script:
 public void BallMove()
        {
            Random randy = new Random();
            int randMov = randy.Next(1, 4);
            int ball_velocity = 3;
            {
                if (randMov == 1)
                {
                    ballRect.X += ball_velocity;
                    ballRect.Y += ball_velocity;
                }
                else if (randMov == 2)
                {
                    ballRect.X += ball_velocity;
                    ballRect.Y -= ball_velocity;
                }
                else if (randMov == 3)
                {
                    ballRect.X -= ball_velocity;
                    ballRect.Y += ball_velocity;
                }
                else if (randMov == 4)
                {
                    ballRect.X -= ball_velocity;
                    ballRect.Y -= ball_velocity;
                }
            } 
        }
```

And yet my ball doesnt move :/ Stays right at its spawn point

Comment: Have you tried adding break-points and stepping through your code? I would try that first, step through the code, line by line to determine the state of your `isRoundPlayin` field, as well as the `ballRect` object and its properties. Perhaps your `X` and `Y` properties are being updated, but does a method or function or something need to be called on `ballRect` after the coordinates are set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you're setting is round playing to true right after moving. Therefore it moves one frame then never updates again. I'm not sure why you would want the round to end when the ball moves one frame. If you gave us more information as to what you are after we might be able to help you out, but at the moment, just removing isRoundPlaying = true from the if statement would get your ball rolling.

Comment: @Slubberdgullion Well the reason I did that becouse without setting it to true every time the BallMove function is read by cpu it gets random number foreach frame and the ball changes its direction al the time but still goes forward-down in window bu with weird ball movement, i just want to make pong and at the beggining of the each round ball should randomly move to one direction, and at the beggining of anither round it would  again generate one other random direction

Comment: Thats because you are generating the random number every time you try to move the ball. The random number should only be calculated once, inside some sort of StartRound function.

Right now, your BallMove function has two responsibilities: Generate a direction, and move the ball. Your move ball should technically look something like:
    ball.Position += Direction * Speed;
or
    ball.Position += Velocity.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alfredth/2009/03/17/pong-a-simple-hands-on-lab-for-xna-game-studio/
That link is a tutorial on how to make pong in an OOP manner.